# How do Log Out User When Session Expires

Tags: asp.net, session, asp.net-mvc-5

I have implemented the session in my app by the following code in

> web.config

```
<sessionState cookieless="false" mode="SQLServer" sqlConnectionString="Data Source=192.168.0.1\SQLEXPRESS;User Id=sa;Password=123456;" timeout="1"></sessionState>
```

In `Global.asax` file

```
public void Session_end()
{
   Redirect("LogOut");
}
```

But, when session expire the app is not logging out. it showing error at the session variable

> variable is not set an instance of oject

I want to logout the user when the session expires.Thanks in advance

Comment: Please read [ask]. "not working propertly" is not a proper problem description.

Comment: Can you show how you store session values?

Comment: i just place the above code in the web.config and starts the app

Comment: I mean the code you use to verify that this is working.

Comment: sorry i didnt get your question. please explain

Comment: You say _"The session values are not storing"_. Show the code you use to determine that.

Comment: thats the critical thing. i dont know how to write it and were. sorry i am little weak weak in session

Comment: Then it's really unclear to me what you're asking. Try searching "ASP.net MVC sessions" and follow some tutorials.

Answer (score -1):

Use the following code in your web config file:

```
 <sessionState mode="SQLServer"   cookieless="true "
  regenerateExpiredSessionId="true "   timeout="30"   sqlConnectionString="Data Source=MySqlServer;Integrated Security=SSPI;"
  stateNetworkTimeout="30"/>
```

Comment: use of 'regenerationExpiredSessionId' and 'stateNetworkTimeout'

Comment: Please explain what you changed and what problem that will fix. Also, mind your spelling and don't abuse markup.

Comment: when i changed the db, the session is not working. but done all the migration